# Boundary of Convex set under Linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, general-topology, linear-transformations, convex-geometry

In $\mathbb{R}^n$, any line goes to line and any convex set goes to convex set under linear trasformation. But will boundary of convex set also will go to boundary of range of convex set?

Comment: "any line goes to line" - it may happen that a line goes to a point. For example, under zero transformation.

Comment: I was taking any point to be trivial line with slope 0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not if you allow domain and range of $A$ to be of different dimensions. Choose e.g. $$A:\Bbb R^2\to\Bbb R,\quad (x,y)\mapsto x.$$
Take the convex set $[0,1]^2\subset\Bbb R^2$. We have that

$$A(\partial_{\Bbb R^2}[0,1]^2)=[0,1]\not=\{0,1\}=\partial_{\Bbb R}[0,1]=\partial_{\Bbb R}A[0,1]^2.$$

Here $\partial_{\Bbb R^n}C$ means the boundary of $C$ with respect to the standard topology on $\Bbb R^n$.

---

However, if you meant $A:\Bbb R^n\to\Bbb R^n$, then your statement is true.  Let $C\subseteq\Bbb R^n$ be convex. If $A$ is not invertible, then $A(C)$ has no inner points, hence all points of $\partial C$ get mapped to boundary points $\partial A(C)=A(C)$.

But if $A$ is invertible, then $A^{-1}$ is linear too. Linear maps are continuous, hence $A$ is a homeomorphism of $\Bbb R^n$ to itself. And homeomorphisms preseves boundary points.

Comment: Somehow, I believe OP meant $\mathbb R^n\to\mathbb R^n$.

Comment: @A.Γ. You might be right. But I wanted to highlight the vague problem statement. However, I included the other case.

Comment: I think $A(\partial C)=\partial A(C)$ is also true (not only $\subset$) for noninvertible.

Comment: @A.Γ. No. Consider $A:\Bbb R^2\to\Bbb R^2,(x,y)\mapsto(x,0)$ and $C=[0,1]\times \Bbb R$. We have $$A(\partial C)=\{0,1\}\times\{0\}\not= [0,1]\times\{0\}=\partial A(C).$$

Comment: That's a good counterexample.

Comment: sorry but I think I missed why A(C) has no inner points if A is non invertible linear transformation and C is convex?

Comment: @Sushil The image of a non-invertible linear map is a proper subspace of the codomain. A proper subspace has no inner points, e.g. think about a plane or line in $\Bbb R^3$.

Comment: yes because any ball translated to 0 will have n linearly independent vectors. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Since in convex analysis, we often talk about *relative* interior points, if the OP also considers *relative* boundary of a convex set $C$, i.e. the boundary of $C$ within its affine hull, then even when the linear mapping $A$ is from $\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^n$, the relative boundary of $C$ may not be mapped to the relative boundary of the image $A(C)$. This happens when $A$ is not injective.

For example, consider a linear mapping $A: \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ defined as $(x,y)\mapsto (x,0)$ (the ''same'' map as in the previous answer, except its image is now in $\mathbb{R}^2$), then again we have $A(\partial [0,1]^2)=[0,1]\ne \{0,1\}=\partial A([0,1]^2)$, where $\partial$ means the relative boundary.